# Comet-style Long-Poll in AIR using URLStream

Tags: flash, air, comet

I'm attempting to connect to an existing Comet-style long-poll service using an AIR app. The service expects a client to make a GET request with a Connection: Keep-Alive header. This request will remain open for long periods of time so that the server can push data through.
In my app, the connection is terminated with an IOError after 30 seconds.

Is this an undocumented limitation of URLStream? A restriction on adl (I've only been running my app through adl)?

The server does not send any "keep-alive" messages to the client but, unfortunately this is not something i have control over.

**Update**

To test this, I've set up a stripped-down version using a little php script (linked by leggetter below) and am hitting it from a simple AIR app. I'm finding that my connections are closed after 30 seconds whether I use URLStream or URLLoader.
the PHP:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

sleep(40);
echo("START!");

header('Content-type: text/plain');
echo str_pad('PADDING', 2048, '|PADDING');

$sleep_time = 1;
$count = 0;
while($count < 20) {
  echo($count);
  flush();
  $count = $count + 1;
  sleep($sleep_time);
}
echo("end");
?>
```

And the Actionscript:

```
private function beginSubscribeToNotifications():void {
    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(myPHPFile);
    req.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
    req.requestHeaders.push( new URLRequestHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive"));

    _urlLoader = new URLLoader();
    _urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete); 
    _urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
    _urlLoader.load(req);
}

private function onComplete(e:Event):void {
    _message = (String)(_urlLoader.data);
}
```

If i adjust the initial sleep time in the php script to anything over 30 seconds, the IOError event is triggered. If I lower the sleep time, but the request continues adding data past 30 seconds, the onComplete event is called, but _urlLoader.data is empty.

The only way this process completely successfully is if the entire thing is over before 30 seconds elapses.

Comment: I've used URLStream for an HTTP Streaming API in the past so it's not a limitation of the object. This SO answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213549/long-polling-http-streaming-general-questions#answer-7347851) provides a really simple PHP streaming example which you could use to create a sample app to prove your Air app works and then try connecting to the real service.

Comment: Thanks @leggetter, i've used your php example to create a stripped-down version of my issue and updated above. Since you have experience here, any ideas?

Comment: Pleased to see you've resolved this by setting the `idleTimeout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is somewhat embarrassing, but I figured I'd post in case someone else runs in to this. 
I have solved my issue by setting the value of [URLRequestDefaults.idleTimeout](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequestDefaults.html#idleTimeout).

According to the documentation:
*When this property is set to 0 (the default), the runtime uses the default idle timeout value defined by the operating system. The default idle timeout value varies between operating systems (such as Mac OS, Linux, or Windows) and between operating system versions.*

I guess for Windows 7 it was 30 seconds.