# ajax retrieve huge data from server

Tags: javascript, ajax

My ajax code is

```
function senddata()
{
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4)
        {
            document.getElementById("showdata").innerHTML=ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }

    ajaxRequest.open("GET", Handler.php?key=" + value, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
```

I have huge amount of data that gets retrieved through ajax. Now when i call this function, it takes much time to show data. I want here is that as the data gets retrived, it should be displayed on the screen. No need to show whole retrieved data only when everything is fetched but display data as it gets fetched.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing partial response using AJAX or WebSockets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952448/accessing-partial-response-using-ajax-or-websockets)

Comment: fetch data page by page(ex. limit 100) and append

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to approach this with the same style of thinking as if you were implementing a pagination system.

I cannot see your `Handler.php` code, so it might make things difficult as we need to edit things in there.

1. Make `Handler.php` accept `limit` and `offset` or `page` query var(s)
2. Add the appropriate code in your PHP to handle that (and the case where none are provided, don't just sent everything! default `limit` to `10` and `offset` to `0`.)
3. Functionalize your ajax request and make it paginate:

   ```
   function getdata(limit, offset)
   {
        limit  = limit || 10;
        offset = offset || 0;

        var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

        // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
       ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
       {
          if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4)
          {
              document.getElementById("showdata").innerHTML=ajaxRequest.responseText;

              // make Handler.php send 'end' when no results have been returned
              if (ajaxRequest.responseText && ajaxRequest.responseText != 'end') {
                getdata(limit, offset + limit);
              }
          }
       }

      ajaxRequest.open("GET", Handler.php?key=" + value + '&limit=' + limit + 
        '&offset=' + offset, true);
      ajaxRequest.send(null); 
   }

   getData();
   ```

Just make sure `Handler.php` sends `end` when there is no more data.