# PHP - long polling for notifications (PHP flags or another way?)

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io, comet, long-polling

Im starting a new project very soon, and im considering long polling to notify the users that they have a new private message/Notification that they have to check, really similar to how Facebook uses to notify you that someone has posted something about you/Liked a photo of you..

From what I have read, cometd seemed like a really good option to start with.

Then, other ways started emerging, like: Socket.io, and node.js ..

Now, my question is; Which one do you think is the best option for this case and why?

What I need to do exactly is the following;

- User 1 logs into their account
- User 2 sends User 1 a message which gets stored into the database and a flag is generated, (If possible?!)
- The PHP script responsible for User 1 should pick up the flag, and push a notification to User 1

I know how to take care of the javascript side, but I have never done anything similar to long polling.
Im using jQuery as javascript library and PHP for the server side.

So recommendations and any good resources to do this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213549/long-polling-http-streaming-general-questions

Comment: I missed that. Im going to read it, thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be beneficial to use a combination of php and also node.js. node.js is made for use with persistant connections, and push communication instead of poll.

http://nodejs.org/

Here is a quick video i found: http://vimeo.com/29099827