# What is the best way to handle streaming JS content in browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, server-side, http-streaming

Imagine we have a server side application that generates streaming content full of JavaScript commands. The easiest way for me to show the example application is to use Python/Flask, however you can perform it using any language just flushing the output after each iteration. So, for a sample server side application:

```
from time import sleep from flask import Response

@app.route('/stream', methods=['POST']) def stream():
    def generate():
        for i in range(10):
            sleep(1)
            yield 'console.log("Iteration: %d");\n' % i
    return Response(generate(), mimetype='application/javascript')
```

which returns (during 10 seconds with 1 second pauses) this kind of output:

```
console.log("Iteration: 0");
console.log("Iteration: 1");
console.log("Iteration: 2");
...
console.log("Iteration: 9");
```

I need to create a "parent" HTML/JavaScript page which handles and executes these commands on-the-fly, i.e. **not** waiting until all 10 iterations will be loaded. Also, it should be able to serve **POST** requests to the mentioned server side application.

Here are the options which I have tried.

1. I tested jQuery Ajax method with different options but it still
   needs full generated output to execute all commands at once.
2. The other idea was to use `iframe`. It works fine but in order to
   use it I need to rephrase my output from `console.log("Iteration:
   0");` to `<script language="JavaScript">console.log("Iteration:
   0");</script>` with content type *text/html*; and also to simulate
   POST form submission to the target `iframe`.
3. I have read about WebSockets. However, since this technology is not
   absolutely supported at the moment, and my application should be
   able to work with on-the-fly content already now, I refused to deal
   with it.

Another very important thing: the **output should be a stream**, since server side application works with a long lasting process; so make `setTimeout(function() { $.ajax(...); }, 1000);` is not the solution.

To summarize, I have tried several options but simple `iframe` is the only solution which really works at the moment. Otherwise, most probably I am missing something. Any thoughts and constructive ideas are very much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure this is even possible and if it is, certainly not advisable.  It sounds like you really should be using a push server with web sockets.  If you have to support older browsers, then polling javascript as a fallback...

Comment: Can Comet help you? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213549/long-polling-http-streaming-general-questions

Comment: @Bergi, not really. The accepted answer in that question did not really convince me, since possibly something has changed from the last node reply (maybe there are some new plugins invented to automate the XHR or `iframe` controlling). Moreover, I disagree that `iframe` is a drawback, except error handling issue this is the only "technology" that worked for me correctly in all browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

long-Polling and comet are options, but these are hacks. The Iframe method you mentioned isn't terrible, but has some state issues if you need to recover the connection.

I would encourage you to reconsider web sockets. There is a lovely shim [available](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js) on github which uses flash (which has had socket support for some time now) as a fall back. You can write client side code as if web sockets exist, and the shim adds it to browsers that don't support it. Great!

Comment: Nice idea, thanks! I will definitely test Flash/WebSocket in my context.