# how can i refresh only when page has changes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Ok so i have this set up where my main.php is the main view area and i want it to fetch getboardajax.php only when there is changes to that file. that file is currently grabbing data from database and if i were to have the .load ajax refresh at say 30 seconds that would work but if im typing in a comment and im in the middle of typing a comment and then it refresh well thats a problem. so i was wondering if there is a possible way to not encounter this problem or is there another way to go around this and how?

**main.php**

```
<div id="postwrapper">
    <div id=div1>
        <p> some text here fetched from mysql database</p>
    </div>
    <div class='div2'>
    <form method='POST' action=''>
        <input type='text' id='commentbox' name='commentbox' autocomplete='off'>
        <input type='submit' value='Post Comment'>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>

$('#postwrapper').empty();
    var $scores = $("#postwrapper");
    setInterval(function () {
        $scores.load("grabboardajax.php #postwrapper");
    }, 3000);
```

**grabboardajax.php**

```
<div id="postwrapper">
    <div id=div1>
        <p> some text here fetched from mysql database</p>
    </div>
    <div class='div2'>
    <form method='POST' action=''>
        <input type='text' id='commentbox' name='commentbox' autocomplete='off'>
        <input type='submit' value='Post Comment'>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try looking at long-polling with ajax and jquery: http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery

Answer (score 0):

There is no fast and easy answer to what you are seeking, but there are several options for you to consider:

- [Ratchet](http://socketo.me) --> My favorite
- [How to implement comet in PHP](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start)
- [php-websocket on github](https://github.com/nicokaiser/php-websocket)
- [phpwebsocket](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/)

Also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213549/long-polling-http-streaming-general-questions) about long polling as it may be the closest thing to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @this.Tony well you are the only one who can answer that question :) It depends on your needs actually. Stack Overflow uses web sockets to notify you of new edits and comments to the page. If you noticed it doesn't apply the update automatically, it puts a little notification bar that says "An edit was made to this post. click to refresh it". Maybe that is what you need. Just get the data, but don't put it directly in your page. show a notification and let the user himself show it when it's convenient for him.

Comment: ok but say since ajax is refreshed every 30 seconds how can i make it where it doesnt replace everything but the new data

Comment: @this.Tony there are several approaches, but the simplest thing would be to load the data into a hidden div, so instead of `$scores.load("grabboardajax.php #postwrapper");` make it something like `$("#myHiddenDiv").load("grabboardajax.php #postwrapper");`. Once the user clicks the notification to apply the update copy the contents from `#myHiddenDiv` to `#postwrapper`.

Comment: that makes sense although say im echoing the grabbaoardajax.php data in a foreach loop in this case it will echo out 40 different divs, im guessing your way will work within this also?

Comment: @this.Tony I'm not sure what your last comment mean. Add the piece of code you are talking about to your question so that we can review it.